# While running selenium webdriver, Below given radio button command is not working in firefox driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running Selenium webdriver, below given radio button command is not working in Firefox driver"

```
java.util.List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.name("user_mar_status"));
radio.get(1).click();
```

kindly refer screenshot.[image]
But this command is working in Chrome driver. Kindly give me a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? what is happening?

Comment: Don't post code as picture, post it as text.

Comment: ok sir. By default radio button select 1st value(Male). But, i can select 2nd value(Female) for using the above command. above command running chrome driver. But, it is not running firefox driver.

Comment: are you getting any error, exception? how many elements do you find? can you share the html code you are trying to click? how about using *findElement* rather than *findElements* ?

Comment: Sir, I have attached html code screenshot

Comment: The name is "user_mar_status", but the radio buttons are gender.  I get that you say it works on x but not y, but when a gender element is named "user_mar_status" I have to wonder if that's the cause.  One would think user_mar_status would be marital status - married/single/divorced/ etc.

Comment: According to your screen shot, you're using the wrong name value.

Comment: Are you using Geckodriver or legacy firefox driver?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, I think you have either posted the wrong code or are using the wrong locator for the elements you are talking about.

I write functions for things like this so they are reusable.

```
/**
 * Sets the gender based on the value passed in
 * 
 * @param gender
 *            Must be a string "M" for male or "F" for female
 */
public static void SetGender(String gender)
{
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='user_gender'][value='" + gender.toUpperCase() + "']")).click();
}
```